# How to paste values from a tab delimited table into a second file matching a word in column 1 from the first file

Tags: python, bash, awk

I have a CD-hit result file (for who is familiar with CD-hit). I want to paste the second column value from another file which is a 2-column tab delimited table into the CD-hit file next to the respective matching RUN ID (like that highlighted with green in the sample image). RUN ID is the 1st column in the tab delimited table (below).[sample image for CD-hit file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1i2kp.png)

CD-hit result file (first file)

```
>Cluster 0
0   108nt, >ERR123456.1016542.1... *
1   108nt, >ERR123456.3114223.2... at +/93.52%
2   108nt, >ERR345678.217087.1... at -/89.81%
3   108nt, >ERR345678.291581.2... at -/92.59%
4   108nt, >ERR567890.3381351.2... at +/87.96%
5   108nt, >ERR987654.126640.2... at -/86.11%
6   108nt, >ERR987654.2492930.2... at +/84.26%
7   108nt, >ERR987654.3327702.1... at +/92.59%
>Cluster 1
0   108nt, >ERR876543.626414.2... *
1   108nt, >ERR123456.3213598.2... at +/85.19%
2   108nt, >ERR567890.1158706.2... at +/97.22%
3   108nt, >ERR345678.146372.1... at -/88.89%
4   108nt, >ERR765432.201531.2... at -/92.59%
5   108nt, >ERR765432.2770540.1... at -/87.04%
```

Tab-delimited table (second file)

```
 ERR123456   1650
 ERR345678   2350
 ERR567890   1520
 ERR876543   4520
 ERR987654   3960
 ERR765432   2550
```

I want the output file to contain the values in the 2nd column from the tab delimited table next to the line that contain its respective RUN ID (1st column in table).

```
>Cluster 0
0   108nt, >ERR123456.1016542.1... *             1650  #matching RUN ID
1   108nt, >ERR123456.3114223.2... at +/93.52%   1650
2   108nt, >ERR345678.217087.1... at -/89.81%    2350
3   108nt, >ERR345678.291581.2... at -/92.59%    2350
4   108nt, >ERR567890.3381351.2... at +/87.96%   1520
5   108nt, >ERR987654.126640.2... at -/86.11%    3960
6   108nt, >ERR987654.2492930.2... at +/84.26%   3960
7   108nt, >ERR987654.3327702.1... at +/92.59%   3960
>Cluster 1
0   108nt, >ERR876543.626414.2... *              4520
1   108nt, >ERR123456.3213598.2... at +/85.19%   1650
2   108nt, >ERR567890.1158706.2... at +/97.22%   1520
3   108nt, >ERR345678.146372.1... at -/88.89%    2350
4   108nt, >ERR765432.201531.2... at -/92.59%    2550
5   108nt, >ERR765432.2770540.1... at -/87.04%   2550
```

Comment: Please show the two input files and the expected, resulting output file - all as text, rather than images. Thank you.

Comment: I edited it as you kindly suggested. Thank you @MarkSetchell

Comment: What will the result be please?

Comment: I cannot see the expected output file :-/

Comment: I explained it at the end of the question. Ok, I will add a sample.

Comment: Please clean up your example. We're looking for some input we can test a potential solution against to see if it produces your expected output but all the `...`s in your input and output make that impossible. Simply post concise, testable sample input and **the** expected output given that input.

Comment: The ...s are included by default in the output of CD-hit. They can be removed using sed for example. What I need is, how we can match values from the second file and paste them in the first one as I explained in the question. @EdMorton

Comment: I added the ...s in the tab delimited table as YOU and many others put (...etc) at the end of the sentence to indicate that there are much of what is said... My trivial easy question has not had valuable answers for a day or so, because someone like you who bothered to comment was just commenting to have some extra reputation or so not to achieve what this site is meant for. Anyways, I don't mean to offend you (as you sadly did) or the other respectable guys who commented earlier, but thank you all. @EdMorton

Comment: Adding `...` to informal text is useful and makes sense. Adding `...` to sample input that people will be running a tool against to see if it produces the expected output (or vice-versa) does not make sense and is not acceptable as it makes the example unusable for testing. I commented to try to help you get an answer to your question, not sure how you think that does anything for my reputation and I'm certainly not offended. You not getting answers is simply the result of how you phrased your question and choosing to ignore the advice I gave you and the link I provided to help you fix it.

Comment: Thank you for this reply. Alright, I can put numbers in the tab delimited table. CD-hit results contain (...) by default which can be substituted by spaces or tabs. I can do it. What else do you suggest to do?@EdMorton

Comment: I have edited the question to remove the dots. The files now are of the same exact form I have but the latter are huge. I would be thankful too if someone told me how after this matching to extract each cluster in a discrete file having the name of the cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{map[$1]=$2; next} {print $0, map[$2]}' FS='\t' tab.txt FS='[>.]' OFS='\t' cd.txt
>Cluster 0
0   108nt, >ERR123456.1016542.1... *    1650
1   108nt, >ERR123456.3114223.2... at +/93.52%  1650
2   108nt, >ERR345678.217087.1... at -/89.81%   2350
3   108nt, >ERR345678.291581.2... at -/92.59%   2350
4   108nt, >ERR567890.3381351.2... at +/87.96%  1520
5   108nt, >ERR987654.126640.2... at -/86.11%   3960
6   108nt, >ERR987654.2492930.2... at +/84.26%  3960
7   108nt, >ERR987654.3327702.1... at +/92.59%  3960
>Cluster 1
0   108nt, >ERR876543.626414.2... *     4520
1   108nt, >ERR123456.3213598.2... at +/85.19%  1650
2   108nt, >ERR567890.1158706.2... at +/97.22%  1520
3   108nt, >ERR345678.146372.1... at -/88.89%   2350
4   108nt, >ERR765432.201531.2... at -/92.59%   2550
5   108nt, >ERR765432.2770540.1... at -/87.04%  2550
```

Comment: Thank you @Ed Morton. I think it may need some modification as it has not worked. It shows the output in the stdout, so I added ">" at the end to direct the output to a third file but it showed only the CD-hit file again. Also after matching, can you tell me how to extract each cluster with its pasted values to a district file having the cluster name?

Comment: After the editing it worked :). Do you have a way to parse the clusters to discrete files?

Comment: Look, you've GOT to show in your question what it is you;re asking to do. This does w3hat you asked for. If you want to do something else but didn't show it then ask a followup question with it's own [mcve].

Comment: Very well. I will do this. Thank you for your help @Ed Morton